# Restdb.io query parent child array, get all where customer's email is jos@gmail.com

Tags: json, mongodb, nosql

When i go to my url /rest/orders i get this. I would like to select * where customer is jos@gmail.com. I can't find something in their documentation about this.

https://collectandgo-6c14.restdb.io/rest/orders?&apikey=5ad8d75725a622ae4d528439

https://restdb.io/docs/querying-with-the-api?utm_source=syndicate&utm_medium=post&utm_campaign=sitepoint-aug17#restdb
[image]

Thanks in advance,
Calvin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
https://collectandgo-6c14.restdb.io/rest/orders?q={"Customer":{"$elementMatch":{"email":"jos@gmail.com"}}}&apikey=5ad8d75725a622ae4d528439
```